# Building AOSP for round display

Tags: rounding, android-source, display, watch

I have running my LeOS-GSI on my smartwatch, but all which are normally shown in the corners, is not available. How can I make a round display with AOSP.

I have tried via overlay

`<bool name="config_mainBuiltInDisplayIsRound">true</bool>`

and build.prop

`ro.emulator.circular=true`

but nothing changed. screen layout still not for round screen